# Системные уведомления на сайте

Tags: уведомления

Прошу дать совет. На сайте планируется сделать уведомления для пользователя двух типов:

1. Личные уведомления;
2. Системные уведомления (общие для всех
   пользователей);

Если говорить про личные уведомления, то тут все просто. Добавляем в БД уведомление для конкретного пользователя (указываем id пользователя) и показываем ему, после того как он прочитал меняем статус на прочитанное.

А как быть с системными, которые предназначены для всех пользователей?
У меня были мысли такие:
Создаю уведомление, добавляю через запятую id всех пользователей на текущий момент в строку 1, и еще тоже самое в строку 2, после того как пользователь прочитал, из строки 2 удаляем его id.

Строка 1 с id пользователями делается для того чтобы не показывать уведомления новым пользователям.

Меня смущает что это может быть ресурсоемким процессом если пользователей будет много.

Может подскажите как лучше действовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и не получил ответ.
Сделал следующим образом.
Таблица personal_notification

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При записи, добавляем id всех пользователей в users_id и not_read_id.
Выводим пользователю по условию:

```
SELECT id, name, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y') as date, IF(not_read_id RLIKE '[[:<:]]{$_SESSION['auth']['id']}[[:>:]]', 'no', 'yes') as readet  FROM personal_notification WHERE users_id RLIKE '[[:<:]]{$_SESSION['auth']['id']}[[:>:]]' ORDER BY date DESC
```

Соответственно он ведет только те уведомления, которые содержат его id

После того как он прочитал уведомление, удаляем его id из not_read_id.

Конечно, знании у меня минимальны, это единственное что смог придумать. Прошу ваши комментарии и советы как это можно улучшить.